# Matplotlib - removing things from axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm looking for method or something, that will allow me to remove **one** thing (I know that cla() will clear whole), for example line from axis, something like:

```
x = self.plt.plot([5*a,0],[0,5*b], color = 'black')
self.plt.draw()
#here I want to to remove x, calculate new position and draw again
```

Everything is beeing done in interactive mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
br@ymir:~/sweethome/temp$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.ion()
>>> l,=plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6],'bo-')      # a figure pops up
>>> l.remove()                              # nothing happens
>>> plt.draw()                              # don't forget to redraw
>>>
```

But if you only want to change the element, you might use `set_ydata(...)` followed by `draw()` instead.